# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Trying to create a to-do list app on laravel but when i try to click on the button the create a new to-do list i get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: tasks.description (SQL: insert into "tasks" ("description", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (, 1, 2017-10-09 03:28:35, 2017-10-09 03:28:35))
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Here is my model for tasks:

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}
```

here is the model for users:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @if (Auth::check())
            <h2>Tasks List</h2>
            <a href="/task" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Task</a>
            <table class="table">
                <thead><tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Tasks</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>@foreach($user->tasks as $task)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{$task->description}}
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <form action="/task/{{$task->id}}">
                                <button type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                                <button type="submit" name="delete" formmethod="POST" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                @endforeach</tbody>
            </table>
        @else
            <h3>You need to log in. <a href="/login">Click here to login</a></h3>
        @endif

    </div>
@endsection
```

Can't seem to figure out the problem and google seems not to have an idea either.

Comment: you have a model as a controller?

Comment: no....what makes you think that?

Comment: Maybe you are not entering data for a field. Check your migration to be sure.

Answer (score 9):

The error you are getting means that there are some columns in the table which have not null constraint and you are inserting/updating null value.

To correct it :

1) Provide a not null value to the column and add to your tasks model snippet below:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'description'];
```

**or**

2) Make the column nullable in the table in your migration file by writing:

```
$table->('description')->nullable();
```

Remove the column name which you made nullable (in your table) from it's tasks model.

=> Empty the database in `phpmyadmin` by deleting all the tables.

=> Run the command : `php artisan migrate`

=> Try performing your action again.

Comment: this didn't work...maybe it is because i'm using sqlite instead of mySql

Answer (score 2):

To your Tasks model, try to add:

```
protected $fillable = ["description", "user_id"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh your database tables. You have a `column` in database which doesn't exist in your Model or migration. and you are not entering data for that field. I just DROPPED all my tables and ran migrations. 
`php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was entering the same unique id which was previously inserted and after deleting that particular record, it worked. Also if you have a opened SQLite database browser, try closing that completely { "PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked", this error was coming back then }. It worked for me. I know its a noob solution but thought sharing this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of description values in tasks table is null.

Here is the way how to fix that-

1. If description can be null, than make it nullable from database table structure.
2. Add `$fillable` property on model-

   ```
   class Task extends Model
   {
       //add this
       protected $fillable = ["description", "user_id"];

       public function user()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: this didn't work...maybe it is because i'm using sqlite instead of mySql