# Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint
>   failed: users.password
>   (SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "username", "updated_at",
>   "created_at") values (MADHUP KUMAR, chandrashivam99@gmail.com,
>   Vansh123, 2020-06-12 09:38:46, 2020-06-12 09:38:46))

http://127.0.0.1:8000/register

**user.php model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','username','password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
         'password','remember_token',
    ];
```

**create_user_table.php migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'username' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5','unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],

    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' > Hash::make($data['password'])
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[23000\]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638534/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-19-not-null-constraint-failed)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `=` in your array. In your create method change

```
'password' > Hash::make($data['password'])
```

To

```
'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to this:
Goto app>Models>User.php and add username to the fillable function.

```
    protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'username',
];
```